# How to center form in visual studio design view?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, user-interface

I have run into strange problem how to center form inside design view in visual studio? Because designing small form with 30" monitor is bit pain in the ... :D I have looked everywhere but haven't found where to set to fix this maybe someone knows how to?

Answer (score 4):

Not a technical solution, but good enough for me.  :P

Just pin the Tool Box to left and Properties to the right and adjust their widths.!  Viola..!!! You have a centered form in the design view.!!!  :)

[image: Just took this screen shot to give you an idea]

Comment: Cool but in 30" display you have to make like 700px toolbox :D